# Figure out largest value in array of numbers

Tags: java, math

I want to be able to calculate the largest value in a list of numbers

I want the type of number to be any number (it should work with double, int, long, etc)

The method that I tried to create for this is not working and keeps returning the first value of the array

```
public static <V extends Number & Comparable<V>> V max(final V... numbers) {
    V currentLargest = numbers[0];
    for (V value : numbers) {
        int arraySize = 0;
        if (currentLargest.compareTo(numbers[arraySize]) < 0) {
            currentLargest = numbers[arraySize];
        }
        arraySize = arraySize + 1;
    }
    return currentLargest;
}
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there are a few issues with the code you have written. First off, I would recommend putting in a check to make sure the numbers array is not null. While this is not required, I would still recommend it. However, the most significant issue you are having is how you are attempting to compare your `currentLargest` value to a value on the array. You are always comparing against the first value of the array every single time as you have your `arraySize` variable updated to zero with every iteration of your loop.

I created a method that does exactly what you are asking with the bugs from your method fixed. I hope this helps.

```java
    public static <V extends Comparable<? super V>> V max(final V... numbers) {
        if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        V currentLargest = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (currentLargest.compareTo(numbers[i]) < 0) {
                currentLargest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return currentLargest;
    }
```

Comment: **Excellent**. I wrote almost the same answer (since deleted). Small tweak, why not make it `<V extends Comparable<? super V>>` then it's generic to any `Comparable<V>`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is a really good suggestion. I will go ahead and change my answer to reflect that.